# Is there an error in my proof of existence of a solution to this integral equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this proof to show that $$x(t) = \log(1+t) + \frac{1}{5} \int^1_0 e^{-t} \cos ^2(ts)(x(s))^2 ds  $$ has a unique integral solution in $C[0,1]$.

I was looking at someone who had posted an identical question to this here: [Show that the integral equation has a solution on a suitable subset of $C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259735/show-that-the-integral-equation-has-a-solution-on-a-suitable-subset-of-c0-1) where someone answered that you need to be careful about which subsets of $C[0,1]$ you choose. I didn't take any care about subsets  at all in my own proof so I was wondering if someone could tell me precisely where I went wrong in the following sketch of my proof. Help is truly appreciated.

Sketch of proof at first is that I show that for all $t\in [0,1]:$ $$\frac{1}{5} \int^1_0 e^{-t} \cos ^2(ts)(x(s))^2 ds $$

is continuous with respect to $t$. (and thus locally Lipschitz given the closed bounded interval).

Then I define $$T_x(t) = \log(1+t) + \frac{1}{5} \int^1_0 e^{-t} \cos ^2(ts)(x(s))^2 ds  $$

which has a fixed point at:

$$x(t) = \log(1+t) + \frac{1}{5} \int^1_0 e^{-t} \cos ^2(ts)(x(s))^2 ds  $$

Then from the lemma above that the integral is continuous, $T$ is also continuous and thus we have that $T: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$.

Then I make the following argument that $T$ is a contraction map.

$$|T_{x_1}(t) - T_{x_2}(t)| = \frac{1}{5} \Big|\int ^1_0 e^{-t} \cos^2 (ts) (x_1(s)-x_2(s))ds\Big| \leq \frac{1}{5} \text{max}_{s\in[0,1]} \Big|x_1(s)-x_2(s)\Big|$$

Thus $\Big\| T_{x_1} - T_{x_2} \Big\| \leq \frac{1}{5} \Big| x_1 - x_2 \Big|$, so $T$ is a contraction map, and since $C[0,1]$ is complete then $T$ has a unique fixed point. Thus there is a unique solution.

If this is correct or if I am missing something fundamental? Thanks for the time.

Comment: Where did the $(x_1)^2$ terms go?

Comment: Oh I think I see the problem

Comment: I think that you can only show that $\Vert T_{(x_1)} - T_{(x_2)} \Vert \le \frac{1}{5}\Vert x_1^2 - x_2^2\Vert$ which is not sufficient to show that $T$ is a contraction. In particular I think that the error occurs after when you write $|T_{x_1}(t) - T_{x_2}(t) |$.

Comment: yeah damn forgot about the square

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: You can show, at a first glance, that $T$ maps $X=\{x\in C([0,1]):\|x\|_\infty \le 2\}$ into itself. You can replace the upper bound $2$ with the smallest positive solution to $b=1+\frac{1-e^{-1}}5b^2$.